# How to get the touch position while dragging

Tags: flutter

I would like to get the touch position while dragging and perform a setState(position). (In Android: getTouchPositionFromDragEvent). I can't find anything that I could use in the Draggable class but maybe there is a work around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use GestureDetector for that:

for example:

```
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragDown: (DragDownDetails details) {
    print(details.globalPosition);
  },
  child: // ...
)
```

see https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html
for more detail.

Or you could use a Listener to get raw data Pointer position.

```
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
    print(event.position);
  },
  child: // ...
)
```

See https://flutter.io/gestures/ to have a comparison between Listener and GestureDetector.

Comment: I tried that but you can't combine a GestureDetector and a Draggable. If you use both the first one will be omitted. Maybe I could simulate a Draggable with a GestureDetector and move the draggable image dynamically?

Comment: @user1273768 you need to specify `GestureDetector.hitTestBehavior` as `HitTestBehavior.translucent`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help

Comment: Listener did the job :-) Thank you so much

Comment: Finally a useful answer. Listener one fixed the issue. Thank you.